# How should I store data to make it easy and efficient to search in android

Tags: android, search

What I have is an app that displays some documents. In the string resources I have the documents divided into smaller pieces in anticipation of making them searchable. Think of them like newspapers with a number of articles where each article is a separate string resource. There will not be any storing of user input (unless I decide to store recent searches). In the search part of the android developer docs it mentions this but says it is not going to go into details of how to store and search data just how to use the search dialog and widget.

What kind of storage of my data should I be using. Is simple string resources good? should I look into a real databasing? which of these make it the most efficient and quickest to search? I'm new to android so any help would be appreciated.

answer:using android's built in sqlite database system and FTS3 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use a database for this.
Read all the documents and link each word to each document in a database.
A word search would then produce a list of documents containing this word quickly.
Make sure you reindex each time you add and remove a document.

By the way, you should see to improving your accept rate.

Also, this is problably not a Android question.